# import: command not found

Tags: python, mingw-w64

I have this code in `myname.py`:

```
# myname.py
def get_name():
    return "Jim"
```

and this in `hello.py`:

```
# hello.py
import myname

name = myname.get_name()
print("hello {}".format(name))
```

When I try to execute `hello.py` in the MINGW64 shell, this error happens:

```
b2b@DESKTOP-5QEK604 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Python moje projekty/Dev/apiarena_django/git (master)
$ ./hello.py
./hello.py: line 2: import: command not found
./hello.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello.py: line 4: `name = m.get_name()'
```

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a Python script as a command, without using the "python" command, your first line has to tell the system what interpreter to use.  This is called a "she-bang" line.  You can either type "python hello.py" or replace the first line with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

As it is, the system is trying to run your command as a bash script.  There is no "import" command in bash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried earlier ` $ ./hello.py python3 ` and ` $ ./hello.py python`. I thought that I indeed tried to run it via python - for some reason, some people suggested that the "python" statement should be after the directory path. Do you have any idea why they thought so? Is it different on Mac?

Comment: No, it's identical on macOS. The `#!` convention is widespread these days but the <command-name> <arguments> convention is even older, dating back to the 1960s if not before.

Comment: wow, so it's even stranger that someone suggested that way. I will try to find those threads with these old school answers and ask why it was posted.

Comment: more about "she-bang" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer was covered by Tim Roberts implicitly, but to be more explicit, it is just context switching from shell scripting to python; a mistake I have made and thus stumbled across this.  Normally run a python file with the python command ... unless you really were trying to run a shell script that had python code.

```
./myPyFile.py
```

--> needs env set at top of file with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

versus:

```
> python myPyFile.py
```